# smalltalk squeak error: "Instances of undefinedObject are not indexable"

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I have problem many time understanding the errors i get in the squeak program, and unable to fix and debug it. like in this case:

I wrote the following code is smalltalk language in squeak:

```
initilize

super initialize.
path := OrderedCollection new.
```

-

```
drawOn: aCanvas
| colors |
colors := Color wheel: 10.
colors withIndexDo:[:c :i | 
aCanvas fillOval: (self bounds insetBy: self width/25*i+1 )
color: c
].
```

-

```
handlesMouseDown: evt
^true.
```

-

```
mouseDown: evt

self position: self position + (10@0).
```

-

```
startAnimation

    path reset.
    0 to: 9 do: [:i | path add: self position +(0@(10*i))].
    path := path, path reverse.
    self startStepping.
```

-

```
step

path size > 0 ifTrue: [self position: path removeFirst].
```

and this is the code I wrote in the workspace:

```
myMorph := TestMorph new openInWorld.
```

but I am getting and error that I wrote up, something about problem with "size" in "step" method
can someone see the problem?

Comment: The error means that your `path` variable in `#step` method is `nil`. I cannot see problem in your code though. Either you do something more, you we need someone keener you spot the problem :)

Comment: @Uko is right, I also fail to spot an error here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you get an error message about `UndefinedObject` it often means that some variable was not initialized correctly, it has the value `nil`.

The error is that you misspelled `initialize`

You wrote `initilize` instead. This method is not called when creating your object and thus the `path` instance variable is let undefined (nil).